# update a tensor(not a Variable)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to update values in a `Tensor`, which is not a Variable.

If `noise_matrix` is a Variable, I can do as followed:

```
tf.assign(noise_matrix,tf.scatter_nd_update(noise_matrix,colmns,newvalue))
```

However, I want to use a GradientDescentOptimizer,which optimizes all variables in the Graph. But `noise_matrix` is not to be optimized because it is only a Tensor to store some values.

How should I update this Tensor but not optimizing it by GradientDescentOptimizer? Help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can set the argument "trainable" to False.

`tf.get_Variable(name, shape, trainable=False)`

Or you create a `tf.placeholder` for the noise and fetch a new noise by every training step or epoch.